# How to make the long title (in the 1st page) into a short form in the next pages?

Tags: formatting

I have latex editor `TexStudio`.

When I write an article, I use  `\title {}` for title  and using documentclass `\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}`.

But if I have a two-line title, I need to reduce the title to a short form which displays in the next pages also.

For example, suppose I have the main title:

```
The image of a set in the quadratic field extension of
a field of characteristic $0$ by a given function
```

Now I want to display this whole in the 1st page but I want to make it in short form like:

```
The image of a set in a extension by a given function
```

How to make the long title (in the 1st page) into a short form in the next pages?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico, \documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use the `amsart` document class, you may employ the following method to define both a "long" or ordinary title string and a "short" title string for use in header rows.

```
\title[The image of a set in an extension by a given function]{%
The image of a set in the quadratic field extension
of a field of characteristic \boldmath $0$ by a given}
```

Observe that the short form is contained in the first, optional argument of `\title`.

Comment: Thank you very much.It worked perfectly.